# Why passing data between View Controllers works with segue

Tags: ios, oop, uiviewcontroller, segue

Why does the following code from [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) work ? :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailSegue"])
     {
         ViewControllerB *controller = (ViewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;
         controller.isSomethingEnabled = YES;
     }

}
```

Everything that I see is that he creates an instance of the ViewControllerB class . I don't understand how that instance (controller) can be the actual ViewController to which it is passing that data? What concept am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is *not* instantiating a new `ViewControllerB` instance. By the time `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called, the view controller has already been instantiated by the storyboard and assigned to the passed-in segue's `destinationViewController` property. So the code is, in fact, just getting a reference to the view controller that has already been created and will be used in the segue.

See the section [Segues Automatically Instantiate the Destination View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW6) in the *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS*:

> A segue represents a triggered transition that brings a new view
>   controller into your app’s user interface.
>
> Segues contain a lot of information about the transition, including
>   the following:
>
> - The object that caused the segue to be triggered, known as the sender
> - The source view controller that starts the segue
> - The destination view controller to be instantiated
> - The kind of transition that should be used to bring the destination view controller onscreen
> - An optional identifier string that identifies that specific segue in the storyboard
>
> When a segue is triggered, iOS takes the following actions:
>
> 1. It instantiates the destination view controller using the attribute values you provided in the storyboard.
> 2. It gives the source view controller an opportunity to configure the new controller.
> 3. It performs the transition configured in the segue.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. When creating that controller , I will assign to it the memory adress of segue.destinationViewController which is a reference to the actual ViewController which I am passing data to, so controller will actually be that ViewController (because it points to the same address as segue.destinationViewController) , right?

Comment: When performing segues that are created in a storyboard (as is the case ~99% of the time), you don't create _or_ assign the view controller at all - it is done for you. You just make use of `prepareForSegue:sender:` to configure ("prepare") that view controller. To facilitate this, a reference to the view controller is accessible to you through the passed-in `segue` (its `destinationViewController` property). So in that sense you're right - `segue.destinationViewController` points to the same memory address as the actual view controller being transitioned to.

Comment: ViewControllerB *controller = (ViewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;  controller will point to the address of segue.destinationViewController ? I'm asking this because I only modify controller.isSomethingEnabled, not segue.destinationViewController.isSomethingEnabled

Comment: Yes. Objects in Objective-C are allocated on the heap and referenced by pointers; you are just passing a pointer reference to a different variable (`controller`). Your question hints that you would benefit from reading ["Working with Objects" in Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html).